# Run an active window inside an PyQT5 GUI application

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5, ros

I'm using PyQT5, and I want to run an external window inside an TabWidget, something similar [to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474647/run-a-foreign-exe-inside-%20a-python-gui-pyqt), but this example is for windows only, and i want to run in a linux (Ubuntu 14.04) os. I also find a similar problem in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883386/how-can-i-embed-another-software-in-my-qt-window-in-linux/57084914#57084914) but the answers didn't work. Also tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015932/how-to-attach-and-detach-an-external-app-with-pyqt5-or-dock-an-external-applicat) but didn't work either. Is possible to embed an terminal, like [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975678/embedding-a-terminal-in-pyqt5), but i have no idea how to do the same with the RViz command. I have some code bellow, who uses **wmctrl** to pick the RViz (the application that i want to embed in my GUI) window ID, and try to put inside the "fromWinID()" class, but the window opens outside my app and also receive the error:

```
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 415, resource id: -1222189812, major code: 7 (ReparentWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 460, resource id: -1222189812, major code: 7 (ReparentWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 461, resource id: -1222189812, major code: 8 (MapWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 463, resource id: -1222189812, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 464, resource id: -1222189812, major code: 12 (ConfigureWindow), minor code: 0
```

Can someone help with that please?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import subprocess
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE, check_output

class Container(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        rvizCommand = 'rviz'
        # Using Popen instead of Call to dont block the process
        subprocess.Popen(rvizCommand, stdout=PIPE,
                         stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
        # wmctrl to find the active hexadecimal   
        lookForID = "wmctrl -l | grep -i RViz | awk '{print $1}'"
        rvizID = subprocess.check_output(lookForID, shell=True)
        rvizID = str(rvizID.rstrip("\n"))
        print(rvizID)
        window = QtGui.QWindow.fromWinId(rvizID)
        container = QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(window, self)               
        self.addTab(container, 'RViz')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
rviz = Container()
rviz.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```